# Making place names permanently visible in Google Earth?

Tags: google-earth

It is not possible to make place names permanently visible in Google Earth, only by hovering over the place or zooming in. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you mean the default place names? in the legend there is 'more' expand it and select local place names. see this image for the more icon https://www.wikihow.com/images/thumb/3/31/Use-Google-Earth-Step-9.jpg/aid383868-v4-728px-Use-Google-Earth-Step-9.jpg.webp